Positioning CurvedTextView at bottom of screen [Wear OS]
I want to position a CurvedTextView at the bottom of a ConstraintLayout in Wear OS. But no matter what I do it always positions itself at the top.
My File->New test project's activity_main.xml layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.wear.widget.CurvedTextView
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

The app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" constraint should position it at the bottom of the screen, but this isn't happening and I don't know why.
My activity (in .NET for Android):
using AndroidX.Wear.Widget;

namespace AndroidApp4
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            FindViewById<CurvedTextView>(Resource.Id.clock).Text = "Hello world";
        }
    }
}

Testing on Large Round emulator with API 30. Dependencies on Xamarin.AndroidX.Wear v1.2.0.5 and Xamarin.AndroidX.ConstraintLayout v2.1.4.13.
I'd be very grateful if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Do you want the text to be at the bottom?? If so, add: app:anchorAngleDegrees="180" and app:clockwise="false"

@dect Thank you! That works. If you want to post this as an answer then I'd be pleased to mark it as correct.

So it seems that CurvedTextView ignores constraints of its position. Is that correct?

Not actually, the constraints works, but seems that they write the text around a full circle... if you set a low value for the height or width you will see that the curvature of the text changes... in other words, the size of the "element" is way greater than the size that the text fills, makes sense?

And the constraints is to set the position reference to where the element will be sticked to... so, when you set it to bottom, it means that the element should "float/stick" to the bottom of the reference you set... in other words, the constraints doesn't change the properties ("design") of the element, just its position, as a whole

Add the tag bellow to rotate the text:
app:anchorAngleDegrees="180" 

And the tag bellow to change the direcionar of the text:
app:clockwise="false

